# Builder design pattern does not work for me

Tags: c++, builder

I have a problem with a c++ code I just written. The code is a sample of the Builder design pattern. I created an abstract builder class, and two classes inherited from this class: MonsterBuilder and RuffianBuilder. I created a Builder class, this class receives a Monster or a RuffianBuilder, and constructs a new instance of these classes. The problem comes here: if the MonsterBuilder class is used to build a new instance the program terminates with an error (a.exe has stopped working). If the Builder receives a RuffianBuilder, it constructs a new instance without an error. Here is the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Character
{
private:
    // Attributes
    int dex;
    int str;
    int end;

    // skills
    int lockpick;
    int guns;
    int sneak;

    /*****************************************  Setters  ********************************************************/
    // Attribute setters
public:
    void setStrength(const int &s)
    {
        this->str = s;
    }

    void setDexterity(const int &d)
    {
        this->dex = d;
    }

    void setEndurance(const int &e)
    {
        this->str = e;
    }

    // Skill setters
    void setLockpick(const int &s)
    {
        this->lockpick = s;
    }

    void setSneak(const int &s)
    {
        this->sneak = s;
    }

    void setGuns(const int &s)
    {
        this->guns = s;
    }

    int getGuns()
    {
        return this->guns;
    }

    int getStrength()
    {
        return this->str;
    }
};


/* Abstract builder */
class CharacterBuilder
{
protected:
    Character * int_character;
public: 
    Character * getCharacter()
    {
        return int_character;
    }

    void buildCharacter()
    {
        int_character = new Character;
    }

    virtual void buildSkills() = 0; 
    virtual void buildAttributes() = 0;

};

class MonsterBuilder : public CharacterBuilder
{
public:
    virtual void buildSkills()
    {
        int_character->setLockpick(10);
        int_character->setSneak(12);
        int_character->setGuns(50);
    }

    virtual void buildAttributes()
    {
        int_character->setStrength(5);
        int_character->setDexterity(5);
        int_character->setEndurance(5);
    }
};

class RuffianBuilder : public CharacterBuilder
{
public:
    virtual void buildSkills()
    {
        int_character->setLockpick(10);
        int_character->setSneak(12);
        int_character->setGuns(50);
    }

    virtual void buildAttributes()
    {
        int_character->setStrength(5);
        int_character->setDexterity(5);
        int_character->setEndurance(5);
    }
};

class Builder
{
public:
    void setBuilder(CharacterBuilder * builder)
    {
        this->builder = builder;
    }

    Character * getCharacter()
    {
        return builder->getCharacter();
    }

    void buildCharacter()
    {
        //std::cout << builder->buildSkills;
        builder->buildSkills();
        builder->buildAttributes();     
    }

private:
    CharacterBuilder * builder;
};

int main()
{
    Builder B;
    RuffianBuilder R;
    MonsterBuilder Mo;

    B.setBuilder(&R);
    B.buildCharacter();
    std::cout << B.getCharacter()->getGuns();
    std::cout << B.getCharacter()->getStrength();

    B.setBuilder(&Mo);
    B.buildCharacter();
    //std::cout << B.getCharacter()->getStrength();
    return 0;
}
```

What causes this problem? Could somebody explain it?

Comment: I got Segmentation Fault even if I passed `RuffianBuilder`. maybe you were too lucky. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zJqJloM415hptYQC

Comment: But first it prints 505, which means 50 guns and 5 strength. That is the result on my computer after that comes the fault.

Comment: It should be undefined behavior.

Comment: Side note, you're creating a new `Character` on the heap, and aren't destroying it afterwards. This will cause a memory leak every subsequent time you call `buildCharacter()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading uninitlalized variable will cause undefined behavior.

I added `builder->buildCharacter();` to `Builder::buildCharacter()` and then this code seems working well.

```
class Builder
{
public:
    void setBuilder(CharacterBuilder * builder)
    {
        this->builder = builder;
    }

    Character * getCharacter()
    {
        return builder->getCharacter();
    }

    void buildCharacter()
    {
        //std::cout << builder->buildSkills;
        builder->buildCharacter(); // add this line
        builder->buildSkills();
        builder->buildAttributes();     
    }

private:
    CharacterBuilder * builder;
};
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, it worked. But why was it needed? First i created a valid MonsterBuilder type variable: MonsterBuilder Mo; This is passed to the builder before buildCharacter was called. It should not be uninitilaized, is it?

Comment: @FeketeFerenc The `int_character` pointer is uninitialised when used in `buildSkills`. It is only initialised when `buildCharacter` is called.

Comment: Oh, i see. When i create a variable like MonsterBuilder Mo; the internal int_character pointer will not be initilized. Thanks a lot!